# "RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget" Share Internet

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, internet

(Moving this from apple.stackexchange.com)

I've connected my Pi Zero over USB to my OS X laptop and under `Preferences -> Network` it shows up as `RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget`, with a `self assigned IP`.

It says that `RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget has a self-assigned IP address and will not be able to connect to the Internet.`

I'd like it to be able to connect to the internet.

How does one enable this?

Comment: Have you attempted to enable DHCP on your pi? also what have you done so far in attempt to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Preferences > Internet Sharing

First you have to select **RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget** then **Internet Sharing**

[image: Sharing]

Comment: You know what? I had "Share your connection from Ethernet" when I was using WiFi this _entire time_! Lol

Comment: On my mac RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget won't show up.  What can I do=