# "Permission denied" for Raspbian default SSH password

Tags: raspbian, ssh, pi-zero-w, headless, raspbian-stretch

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry Pi Zero W as a headless device on my local network, and am performing the initial setup with a fresh copy of Raspbian Stretch

I've tried installing both the latest Raspbian Stretch lite and the latest Raspbian Stretch with desktop, and was able to get it set up for SSH by configuring the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file with WiFi credentials and creating an empty `ssh` file.

I've tried SSH'ing in from multiple different computers, and the problem is the same every time. I log in with `pi@192.168.0.102`, which I've confirmed to be the devices' IP Address. It asks for the password, so I type `raspberry`, as per the online guides. It does not accept it. It will repeat the `password:`  field 3 times, then ask for `pi@192.168.0.102's password:`.

At this point, I get "Permission denied, please try again". I get the same password query again, and upon entering it:

```
Received disconnect from 192.168.0.102 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures. 
Authentication failed
```

Adding `-v` for debug just shows it trying all my local private keys in my .ssh folder, which are for something else (so they don't work of course) and eventually falling back to `publickey,password,keyboard-interactive`, where it asks for the password again.

I am absolutely certain that `raspberry` is the correct password, as multiple online sources have confirmed it, and I am certain I've type it correctly (I even had a friend type it for me to no avail).

What's going on here?

---

**Edit**: I've tried from MacOS, Windows, and Android (Termux with OpenSSH installed), and I've tried connecting over USB instead of WiFi. The issue persists. Maybe there is some way to generate an SSH key for the pi? (I don't have a Mini HDMI converter so the GUI is not accessible)

**Edit2**: I was able to get into the terminal via USB OTG, and the default password worked. I changed the password. After some tinkering around (I'm not entirely sure what changed), I was able to SSH in via an emulated Ethernet over USB as `pi@raspberrypi.local`. That means my real issue is with connecting to the WiFi - something I've already spent 2 hours trying to get work while connected with g_serial.

**Edit3**: I decided my best course of action was to try and set up a VNC server on the Pi. I was able to successfully share my internet from my work MacBook and SSH in. However, I'm getting errors while running `sudo apt-get install tightvncserver`:

```
Err:41 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf tightvncserver armhf 1:1.3.9-9
Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3 80]
```

`ifconfig` for the USB ethernet connection returns this:

```
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.2.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
inet6 fe80::f87c:94fd:7b3e:454d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
ether 4e:38:f5:71:6e:74  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 2080  bytes 214353 (209.3 KiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 1935  bytes 348268 (340.1 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Pinging mirrordirector.raspbian.org

```
ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org
PING mirrordirector.raspbian.org (93.93.128.193) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C 
--- mirrordirector.raspbian.org ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4151ms
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it's just the wrong keyboard layout. Germans have to type raspberrz because y and z are switched on GB and DE keyboards.

Comment: I'm using U.S. Keyboard layout

Comment: What OS is your client computer? ... GNU/Linux distro? Windows? Mac?

Comment: I've tried using Mac (iTerm), Windows (Putty), and Android (Termux with openssh installed). Same result on every machine.

Comment: Did you try to use the normal terminal on Mac? Maybe also try a reinstall of the image onto the SD card?

Comment: Normal terminal doesn't work. I redownloaded both Raspbian and the Lite version from raspberrypi.org/downloads and both installations are doing it

Comment: Check out my guide on how to debug SSH problems on the server side [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128910/5462). Doesn't mean that there is an SSH problem, but my guess is that password authentication is blocked by default (which is good!) or similar. You may also simply try to add one or more of your existing public keys to the RPi `pi` account under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: Other users in this situation have later realized that the IP address is actually a device other than the Pi Zero. You can confirm whether it is (please edit your post) by using zeroconf i.e. `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` or confirming that 192.168.0.102 goes offline the moment you depower the Pi. Another way to log in headless, assuming you don't have a three-pin serial cable, is g_serial. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67907/debugging-usb-otg-serial-on-the-pi-zero-w/75551 and yes you can generate an ssh key and place it under /home/pi/.ssh/ with Linux and an SD card reader.

Comment: I connected the Pi directly to my Mac and connected to `pi@raspberrypi.local` and got the same result. I also tried installing Raspbian using PiBakery and telling it to set up with an SSH key, but it wouldn't take accept it (May have done that part wrong.) I will try debugging with USB OTG and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the IP address is correct. You also mentioned that you've reinstalled Raspbian twice so that mostly rules out being botnet-compromised (on top of its IP never being visible to the outside world). As g_serial still requires a login and password it seems that may not help at this point. For directly editing `/home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys` and examining `/var/log/auth.log`, I realize you have every OS except for desktop Linux. If your Mac has an SD card reader you can install Paragon ExtFS for Mac. Very curious as to what the eventual answer turns out to be.

Comment: I have Parallels desktop for my Mac, installed Ubuntu on it, and was able to log in via USB OTG. The correct password was indeed `raspberry`, and I successfully changed the password. However, even after changing the password, I am still unable to SSH into the pi. I am getting the same issue as before. I know I am trying to connect to the correct device because it gets far enough to ask for the password for the user 'pi'.

Comment: Awesome! Now you can do some deeper troubleshooting via `ssh pi@localhost` from within the serial console. You may `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` when doing such tests too. If you need to test ssh from outside while still logged in from serial, use `g_multi` instead of `g_serial`. (Note the usual caveat of `options g_multi file=/dev/mmcblk0p1` so that it doesn't complain about an invalid argument to mass storage.) Well, if your wireless is now confirmed working you might as well just use that and stick with g_serial. When you have more logs please edit your post accordingly to include them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured out the issues and got in, here's how I did it.

The Raspberry Pi can only connect to 2.4GHz networks. I had properly configured the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, but I specified a 5GHz network instead of 2.4GHz.

I do not know why it was asking for `pi@192.168.0.102`'s password when that user did not exist on that device, but **don't let it fool you**, just because it shows the user does not mean that the user exists on the machine you're connecting to.

I connected to my Windows machine with `g_ether`, and was able to SSH into the pi from `raspberrypi.local` over USB. From there, I eventually decided to attempt to Remote desktop in. Since I didn't have internet on the Pi, I couldn't use `apt-get`. Therefore, I manually installed RealVNC Server with `dpkg` from [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/raspberrypi/) (You need the Full version of Raspbian, not Lite). Using [MobXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), I was able to transfer the .deb package to the Pi over SSH

After the server was installed on Raspbian Full, I connected to `raspberrypi.local` from the RealVNC client. From there, I could see a list of WiFi networks. Or the 2.4GHz networks, at least. I simply connected to my other network, used `ifconfig` to get the IPv4 address, and was able to SSH into the Pi over WiFi. Problem solved!

Comment: So it sounds like 192.168.0.102 turned out to be the IP address of something other than the Pi Zero. [This tends to be a first culprit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75921/how-can-i-connect-to-my-raspberry-pi-3-over-ssh-in-this-scenario) when troubleshooing most headless scenarios (see the part buried in that question's comments that says 
"Hello @jdonald. So I don't think I have the right IP address for the raspberry pi". One thing that wasn't resolved is why internet connection sharing never worked via `g_ether`, but glad this piece wasn't necessary in the end.

Comment: Hi, Arlo, I connected the PI with an ethernet cable to my iMac. To know the IP address of PI I checked the Ethernet connection in Network in System Preferences.So I typed ssh pi@EthernetIPAddress, I encountered the same problem like you but I don't want to install RealVNC Server like.Can you suggest something that suits my situation?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself puzzled with the password too most of the times. The issue was that my keyboard layout was wrong, so I tried typing "raspberry" while I really typed "raspberrz". Maybe check your keyboard layout. Also double check if SSH really is enabled in the "sudo raspi-config" menu.
Edit: Oh sorry, I really overread the part where you wrote that you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to SSH in with raspberrypi@ip.address will fail as there is no default user name called raspberrypi.

SSH with pi@ip.address will work

Pi Documentation here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/windows10.md

Comment: There is no command like that in the question to begin with. Did you post your answer in the wrong place?

Comment: This looks like you may have mis-read the question.  (I considered that possibly the original question was edited and did check the edit history).  The OP writes that they are attempting to use the 'pi@...' user, which should exist as a default account unless it was disabled or removed.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the original question. :-(

Answer (score 0):

For me it was quite simple:
I always tried to ssh using `pi@<ip-address>`
not realizing `pi` being the user I am trying to log in as.
Since this user did not exist, all password attempts were futile.

The command is:

```
ssh <username>@<ip-address>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, trying to headless is a pain the (insert preferred body part here), and you would be better off just using HDMI or similar to set up the Pi, change the password, and then try SSH-ing into it.

Comment: I don't have a Mini HDMI adapter

Comment: Elaborating on the comment above, raspberrian does not like using U.S. keyboard in the terminal.

Comment: I switched the Mac to Britain layout, authentication still fails

Comment: Did you try reinstalling raspberrian

Comment: I've reinstalled Rasbian twice

Comment: Raspbian has *no* problem whatsoever with a US keyboard layout on the terminal, provided you configure it to use that instead of the preconfigured UK (IIRC) layout.

Comment: Now that the password has worked (at least via g_serial/g_ether/g_multi) and it's back to WiFi troubleshooting, Lucas's answer may not be so far off. Generally users have more trouble troubleshooting wpa_supplicant.conf with the command line compared to the Pixel GUI. Similar to using HDMI, @Chuck Fecht can you try connecting to WiFi from within VNC? I'm assuming by this point you got internet connection sharing working over USB and hopefully have no trouble running apt-get.

Comment: Brilliant idea. I was able to finally share Internet to the Pi via my Mac (Ubuntu gave me an odd error message and wouldn't share), while also successfully SSH'ing into the Pi. However, during installation of `tightvncserver`, I got the error `Err:41 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf tightvncserver armhf 1:1.3.9-9. \n Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 ([mac address]) - connect (101: Network is unreachable)`. It told me what new packages needed to be installed, how much space it would take, etc, so I assume it didn't completely fail?

Comment: Can you even `ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org` or other sites from the Pi? The fact that you can ssh in may just mean it's locally connected but not sharing internet. Yes, Linux has trouble other than "Link-Local Only" (see other questions here on Pi Exchange), but Mac and Windows are solid. On your Mac, does your sharing setup match the screenshot on [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47678/rndis-ethernet-gadget-share-internet)? If you have connectivity but it's a DNS issue, you troubleshoot by using IP numbers or manually setting your DNS server.

Comment: I've updated the question to return Ping results (got no response). I do have it properly set up for Internet Sharing, but further looking into it, the `Router`, `DNS Server`, `Search Domains` fields are all blank. How would I properly configure the DNS for the pi?

Comment: It appears able to DNS-resolve even if unreachable, otherwise it would have said `ping: unknown host mirrordirector.raspbian.org` so I don't think DNS is your issue (if it were you could add a `nameserver` field to `/etc/resolv.conf`). If you're positive that both Internet Sharing + RNDIS/Ethernet Gadget are checked and you've selected the correct Share from *WiFi* vs *Ethernet*, not sure what's failing. Could next try Windows (Note Windows is more troublesome on g_ether, sometimes requiring explicit RNDIS driver install and careful network right-click -> Sharing -> Allow, Select private...)

Comment: I added nameserver (Using Google's DNS server) to `/etc/resolve.conf`, that didn't do much. I've tried sharing from Windows as well now (using instructions found on the majority of websites) and that gave the same result (But it did install the RNDIS driver on its own, and I was able to SSH in using Putty and reinstalling Raspbian stretch lite again). Could it be something to do with the network Gateway? (I assume the gateway acts as a proxy between the Pi and the host computer?)

Comment: I stumbled across this: `https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/raspberrypi/`, so I SHOULD be able to place the file on the SD card and install using `dpkg` from an SSH session. I'll update whether this worked or not after I get back from Christmas vacation.

Comment: Success!!! I've gotten my Pi set up and working. I had to install Raspbian Stretch full (not light) to install RDP, and it turns out the issue was that the Pi Zero W cannot connect to 5GHz networks, only 2.4gz. I connected it to my 2.4 network and it was smooth sailing from there. Thanks for everyone's help! I'll add an answer detailing my problem and solution later